# How to read files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a file on the iOS iPhone emulator (Download folder).

How can my app get the permission to read this file, in Objective-C?
I can get the file path with the following:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentsDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
NSLog(@"%@", filePath);
```

But how can I read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is sandboxed and can access files freely *only* within its own container. For accessing user personal files, you should leverage `UIDocumentPickerViewController` class, and let the user pick the file (him/her)self:

```objc
UIDocumentPickerViewController *pickerVC = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initForOpeningContentTypes:@[
    [UTType typeWithFilenameExtension:@"xml"]
]];
pickerVC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:pickerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then you can access whatever the user selected in the delegate method:

```objc
#pragma mark UIDocumentPickerDelegate

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller
didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)urls {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urls.firstObject
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                             error:nil]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Should I create a class for this? Only for picking the file?

Comment: If you mean `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, it doesn't need to be subclassed, just use it as is with required data properties (extensions, mimetypes, etc) in the object constructor. For the delegate, the method has to be implemented somewhere, of course. As long as you use a view controller to present the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, the most straightforward candidate for that role is probably the presenting controller itself. Either way you have to delegate file picking to the system (and the system itself just asks the user to choose), because of iOS security restrictions

Comment: @Selenium1293 if the answer helped you with solving the issue in the question, I'd appreciate if you upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
So let's say I'm in the class `myClass.m` and I need to implement the delegate.
I can just use in `myClass.m` the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and then I need to call another class which will be the delegate? Sorry I never did that I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: @Selenium1293 in order to present an instance of `UIDocumentPickerViewController` you should use another controller (there are other less widespread options, but we can ignore it for now), so the first part of the snippet comes in one of the controller methods (it might be a response to some button click). In this case (since the sample uses `pickerVC.delegate = self;`) this presenting controller is responsible for handling the response. You may refer to [this snippet](http://tpcg.io/_XO4JTB) for more complete example...

Comment: @Selenium1293 ..Be advised, however, that i put the code which presents the instance of `UIDocumentPickerViewController` inside of `viewDidAppear:` method for simplicity, but you'll probably want it inside of some button callback instead